# Computed fields in Pydantic V2 - can I add aliases for validation and serialization?

Tags: python, class, validation, inheritance, pydantic

### Context

Within a Pydantic model, I want to set the values of two fields based on the values contained by a third. BUT I'd also like to set some nuanced aliases.

So if we have:

```py
class FooModel(BaseModel):
    data_holder: list = Field(..., exclude=True)

    # Values of bar and baz below will be set based on values in data_holder
    bar: int = Field(..., validation_alias=AliasChoices(‘bar’, ‘Bar’), serialization_alias=‘Bar’)
    baz: int = Field(..., validation_alias=AliasChoices(‘baz’, ‘Baz’), serialization_alias=‘Baz’)
```

And I do:

```
foo = FooModel(data_holder=[123, 456])
```

I want:

```
# The model will compute:
    bar=123 # Field validation and serialization rules apply
    baz=456 # Field validation and serialization rules apply

# Such that:

print(bar)
#> Bar='123'
print(baz)
#> Baz='456'
```

### Question

**--> Is this possible to do using `@computed_field`, or is there another recommended way to do this?**


Computed field seems the obvious way, but [based on the documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/#pydantic.fields.computed_field) I don't see a way to add validation and serialization alias options. I believe `root_validator` provided a solution in V1, but that's deprecated. I've also considered using a "before" `field_validator`, but haven't gotten that to work with my actual use case. (The real-world context is messier and `data_holder` is actually another Pydantic model).